# Separa numeros que tiene un punto en medio y guardarlos en variable

Tags: javascript

miren tengo este problema necesito separar este codigo 5411.21
y guardarlo en variables diferentes, como ven tiene un . en medio

```
$(".o tr").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
    var existencia = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();
    var codigosolo = id.replace("5510.2","5510");
    var tallasolo = id.replace("5510.2","2");
    console.log(codigosolo);
    console.log(tallasolo);
});
```

es lo que intente pero son varios codigo por eso uso el each

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo mirar la documentación del método split https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: no lo eh logrado aun no tengo demasiado experiencia en js algun ejemplo porfavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que "existencia" es tu código separado por un punto, tendrías que usar split:

```
$(".o tr").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
    var existencia = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();
    var existenciaArray = existencia.split('.');
    var codigosolo = existenciaArray[0];
    var tallasolo = existenciaArray[1];
    console.log(codigosolo);
    console.log(tallasolo);
});
```

Comment: sos un capo gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

podrías hacer un split o bien utilizar una expresión regular en este caso por ejemplo

```
new RegExp("(\d{1,})\.(\d{1,})");
```

esto te puede ser útil si deseas separar una cadena mas compleja, digamos un numero de tipo 1,000.00 podrías separarlo fácilmente con expresiones regulares.

Comment: ya logre que funcione gracias